# VBScript Run/Exec setting environment once and reusing

Tags: shell, vbscript, environment-variables

Is there a way to have Run or Exec preserve the environmental variables after each call?

For example, call `vcvars32` that does a lot of configuring of paths and whatever:

`shell.Run "vcvars32.bat", 0, True`

Then I'd like to be able to call `msbuild` in this configured environment:

`shell.Run "msbuild.exe example.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=""Debug|Win32""", 0, True`

Is this possible?

The only alternative I could find is to create a combo batch script with both commands and call that instead. But that seems wasteful if I need to call the setup script each time, it would be great to have the environment set up once and then reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the calls for vcvars32.bat and msbuild.exe in one batch file. Use `CALL` to call vcvars32.bat and it will preserve the environment. Pass your SLN and other arguments to the batch file and retrieve them using %1, %2, %3, etc. remember to put quotes around them if needed.

It's not as clean as having everything in one VBS file, but it's the simplest way.

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I didn't think of the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could put it as a function? Im not sure if that answers your final question but it will create a lot less "stuff" you need to remember.
i put the vcvars32.bat in the same function because i do not know whether you would need them in the same function.

```
sub
funcmsbuild
end sub

Function funcmsbuild
shell.Run "vcvars32.bat", 0, True 
shell.Run "msbuild.exe example.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=""Debug|Win32""", 0, True
end function
```

Or else you could put all your environmental variables in a string and call that? But that would be confusing since you have alot of quotes in that "would be" string, and it would require you to have your triple and quadruple quotes in order (unless you used chr(22) i belive for quotes)